# Error while writing a simple code in VS code protractor : ERROR:browser_switcher_service.cc(238)] XXX Init()

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I wrote a simple test in VS Code while working on protractor and got an error while executing on the New Terminal

> DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49813/devtools/browser/be6e2d14-8a42-4b12-8854-7f05dc686c0b
>   [5696:6260:0423/182116.847:ERROR:browser_switcher_service.cc(238)] XXX Init()

Can somebody help me in explaining why this error is coming

Comment: i have it too, seems due the latest chrome version.. :) you should not have issues running the tests.

Comment: consider adding your code.

Comment: I tried using firefox as well. issue is same. the browser is launching but no logs are getting generated

Comment: Just a normal sample testcase that I tried executing 

describe("mysuite",function(){

beforeEach(function(){

console.log("This is login action....")

})

it("mytest1",function(){

    console.log("This is my test1....")
})

it("mytest1",function(){

    console.log("This is my test2....")
})

})

Answer (score 0):

in my case, turns out I missed `https://` part of the url. Once added, it fixed the problem